# Use Nexus on same day as interview?

Tags: borders, nexus

If I attend and pass my Nexus interview at Blaine, WA, can I then cross the border into Canada using Nexus? I'm asking because if I'm driving 2-3 hours to the border it would be nice to make a Canada weekend out of it.

Comment: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1292/~/when-will-i-receive-my-trusted-traveler-card%3F seems to suggest that you don't get the card on the spot; it's mailed to you later.

Comment: Even if the Nexus card isn't sent until later, it's a long drive...you could cross over into Canada without it.

Comment: After you receive the NEXUS card don't forget to activate it online before using it.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/142887/4188

Answer (score 2):

Usually the card is send weeks after the interview, [this site mentions it being 6 to 8 weeks later.](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1292/~/when-will-i-receive-my-trusted-traveler-card%3F)
But nothing stops you using your passport (book or card) to cross into Canada after or even before the interview.
In the case you want to fly, you can use the 'card' before holding the actual card, from the moment you have been approved for it, but this does not work for surface travel.

When you get your card you need to activate it online before you use it to cross a border.