# Do I need my physical NEXUS card to receive benefits at the airport?

Tags: nexus

I was just approved for NEXUS last weekend and I'm still waiting for my card. They said I was "in the program" and everything but said the card could take a while.

So can I use Pre-Check lanes and NEXUS machines using my PASSID number, which I found online? Or do I need to wait until I receive the card?

Comment: what airport? what airline? For example, many US airlines print the pre-check symbol on your boarding pass, but in Toronto I have to show my physical Nexus card to use the "trusted traveler" security line. Also, the US machines are not the same as the Canadian machines.

Answer (score 1):

1. Border crossing. For USA border crossing, you will be using Global Entry machines, these work with your passport. This [guide](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/globalentry-info-guide.pdf) says "Members must use a passport or U.S. legal permanent resident card at Global Entry kiosks." The Canadian border uses NEXUS machines but since any citizen/permanent resident can use the automated machines with just a passport there as well, their advantage is largely diminished / nonexistent. (There are NEXUS members who can't use these machines because their iris scanning failed. I am such.)
2. Security. Again USA and Canada differs. As this [page](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/tsa-pre%E2%9C%93%C2%AE) details, US citizens/permanent residents at US airports with a PASS ID are eligible for TSA Pre. Your eligibility is checked based on your boarding pass. At Canadian airports, to quote the [official page](https://www.catsa-acsta.gc.ca/en/trusted-travellers) "trusted travellers [...] carry special photo identification cards with security features that give them direct access to many airport security screening checkpoints across Canada." However, very often you will only get to jump the queue (although some airports have less stringent security lanes which are either open or not). This [forum thread](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g154943-i81-k11960827-YVR_Security_when_travelling_with_non_trusted_travellers-Vancouver_British_Columbia.html) have reports of the lane dragon allowing access to companions not carrying a NEXUS card as long as one person showed theirs.